# Books for these topics.

Tags: calculus, reference-request, integral-equations

I have an lecturership exam in India and in the syllabus there are few topics under the tags "Calculus of variations" and "Linear integral equations", and if please if someone could tell me which books I should refer, to cover these topics, I will be hugely thankful. Here is the pic-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Calculus of Variations, I recommend the text by [Gelfand and Fomin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486414485)

Comment: For integral equations, Akheizer's posthumous notes and the Handbook of Integral Equations are pretty good (though the latter is more of a reference text).